# Why can't I call static methods anywhere in my Android app

Tags: java, android, static-methods

Whenever I do, no matter where I call it from, the app crashes with **IllegalStateException: could not execute method of the activity**. I only have a few classes at the moment, and they're all in the same package, including the class with the static methods causing the crash.

Is there some issue or special consideration that should be taken into account when calling static methods in an Android app?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    ImageManager.initImageManager(this);  // crash
}
```

**EDIT**
Apologies, the error is actually a **VerifyError**. There seems to be some conflict with the Dropbox API, which I'm using in one of the static methods, but which is not called prior to the app crashing. The following is error output after I changed the ImageManager to be an entirely static class, which I think it should be. ImageManager code follows:

```
01-09 19:23:51.356: W/dalvikvm(32032): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI;)
01-09 19:23:51.357: I/dalvikvm(32032): Could not find method com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.getFile, referenced from method rfynes.moviebrowser.ImageManager.downloadImage
01-09 19:23:51.357: W/dalvikvm(32032): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5140: Lcom/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI;.getFile (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/OutputStream;Lcom/dropbox/client2/ProgressListener;)Lcom/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI$DropboxFileInfo;
01-09 19:23:51.357: D/dalvikvm(32032): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0063
01-09 19:23:51.358: W/dalvikvm(32032): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 735 (Lcom/dropbox/client2/exception/DropboxServerException;)
01-09 19:23:51.358: W/dalvikvm(32032): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x8b
01-09 19:23:51.358: W/dalvikvm(32032): VFY:  rejected Lrfynes/moviebrowser/ImageManager;.downloadImage (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/File;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI;)V
01-09 19:23:51.358: W/dalvikvm(32032): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x008b
01-09 19:23:51.358: W/dalvikvm(32032): VFY:  rejected Lrfynes/moviebrowser/ImageManager;.downloadImage (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/File;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI;)V
01-09 19:23:51.358: W/dalvikvm(32032): Verifier rejected class Lrfynes/moviebrowser/ImageManager;
01-09 19:23:51.358: D/AndroidRuntime(32032): Shutting down VM
01-09 19:23:51.358: W/dalvikvm(32032): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41672898)
01-09 19:23:51.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32032): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 19:23:51.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32032): java.lang.VerifyError: rfynes/moviebrowser/ImageManager
01-09 19:23:51.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32032):    at rfynes.moviebrowser.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
01-09 19:23:51.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32032):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5150)
01-09 19:23:51.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32032):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-09 19:23:51.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32032):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2192)
01-09 19:23:51.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32032):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
01-09 19:23:51.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32032):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148)
01-09 19:23:51.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32032):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1273)
01-09 19:23:51.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32032):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 19:23:51.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32032):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 19:23:51.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32032):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5222)
01-09 19:23:51.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32032):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 19:23:51.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32032):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-09 19:23:51.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32032):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-09 19:23:51.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32032):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-09 19:23:51.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32032):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**ImageManager**

```
public class ImageManager {

private File posterDir, backdropDir;

public static void initImageManager(Activity activity) {
    posterDir = activity.getDir("poster", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    backdropDir = activity.getDir("backdrop", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
    ...
    ...
    public static void downloadImage(String movieId, File imageDir, String imageType, DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> dropbox) {
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace please, that would be helpful.

Comment: Also, can you include the static method causing the problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem with static methods in general, or the static method itself?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do something bad with activity you passed into initImageManager. Like boys said, give us full stacktrace and all relevant code.

Comment: Just to reiterate, the only code differences between the app working and crashing is that I made all methods in the ImageManager static, and I added a static call to initImageManager() from the onCreate() of my activity.

Comment: Did you include the dropbox api as a jar or library project?

Comment: @Submersed: jars, and the only way I could get them to work was to put them into a folder called libs in the project root

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own question in these circumstances.

Comment: Never, ever, pass an Activity instance to another class, especially to static methods.  This is very, very bad.  Instead, use the application context.

Comment: @Simon: I actually do that all the time, when my classes (usually objects) need to use the activity ref for one reason or another. Why is it bad, what's the alternative and do you think that's what is causing the problem?

Comment: Kind of a guess, but from the first line in your stack trace maybe it has something to do with the jar - i.e. "Could not find method com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.getFile" - When I've ran into this issue in the past, I've fixed it by making sure to select the Dropbox api jar under Java Build Path -> Order and Export -> Check dropbox jar.

Comment: It's not causing the crash, but you do understand that Activity life cycle (if not, you should).  If Android destroys and recreates your Activity, the static method holds on to the reference, quite possibly for the lifetime of the app, and you leak all of the memory taken by the activity.  As I say, use the application context or some other method (many discussions on here and Google).  There is never a need to do it - ever.

Comment: @Simon, What you're saying is true if a reference is kept - but since he's not keeping a reference to it (only accessing it during the execution of the constructor), it shouldn't cause the issue you're suggesting, should it?

Comment: @Submersed: Putting the dropbox jar(s) on the build path doesn't work. Something to do with the latest SDK, I've come across other people having the same probleam

Comment: @Submersed With the code shown, no, but it's never right - there are better (correct) ways to handle application resources and activity elements.  All it takes is to come back in 6 months, make a change add a static class field to hold the context or some other element and boom.  I guess what I'm saying is you cannot guarantee the life time and scope of a class with static fields or methods and there is never a requirement to pass an activity reference so why do it?

Comment: I've fixed my code, I'll update with an answer shortly. In reference to what you guys are talking about (I know this is actually a separate Q) but is there a quick answer/explanation about how to allow your objects to get a reference to the activity so they can update the UI, interact with sharedprefs etc. as opposed to storing an activity reference?

Comment: @RTF Never keep strong reference to an activity context, as this could leak the activity's view hierarchy.  The application context can be used to access shared preferences, without this danger.  Also, if you need to communicate back to the activity, you could register a BroadcastReceiver in your activity, and send broadcasts back to your activity using your app context to send the BC.  Also, you can (though it's frowned upon, but isn't really a danger if you handle it correctly) use a WeakReference<YourActivity> to keep a reference to your activity that won't prevent garbage collection.

Comment: Or define `Interface`s(which is common in Android - think about onClickListener - that's an interface).  They're are a great way to keep UI updates where they belong, in the activity.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, I actually ended up breaking the **downloadImage** method (and a couple others) out of the ImageManager class into their own separate non-static class. The ImageManager is still a static class now, but it's not causing any problems and the app is not crashing. So, it appears that the problem was the Dropbox API call(s) that I was making from a static context, but I don't know why exactly. I'm happy enough with what I've got now, though.